# Bootstrap ошибка в примерах

Tags: bootstrap

На странице [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/grid/) все колонки с настройкой `col-md` на айпаде работают неправильно.
Это значит, что для айпада нужно обязательно указывать `col-xs col-sm`,
или это ошибка требующая исправления?

Comment: Что значит работают `неправильно`? Что конкретно происходит?

Comment: В примере Two columns with two nested columns
вложенные ячейки рисуются не внутри родительской, а с вертикальным смещением.

В трех примерах с col-md в книжной ориентации все ячейки рисуются на всю ширину экрана в столбик

Comment: Просмотрел примеры в трех различных браузерах на айпаде (сафари, хром, опера), поведение таблиц везде одинаково некорректно. Похоже, размеры устройства определяются неправильно, реальные размеры - 2048х1536, но в альбомной ориентации используется sm, но работают и другие настройки, в книжной ориентации устройство определяется как xs и все другие настройки игнорируются.
Вертикальный сдвиг непонятно как можно объяснить.
В общем, что-то слишком плохо для фреймворка позиционирующего себя как mobile first.

Answer (score 3):

[[@Fort  Testo](/users/29314/fort-testo)](/users/29314/fort-testo), если вы не понимаете, как работает framework, то это не значит, что технология плохая, а значит, что надо в ней разбираться. И никогда в программировании не делайте поспешных выводов, не разобравшись.

Там всё просто и понятно написано, есть 4 стиля, которые работают при разных размерах браузера, если размер окна браузера не входит в рамки этого стиля, то применяется класс `width: 100%`.

Открываем обычный iPad, к примеру, в Google Chrome, смотрим в альбомном виде на [этот пример](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic), разрешение браузера в альбомном виде: 1024px в ширину. Значит стили col-md, которые работают при размере браузера больше 992px, должны отображаться по их ширине, заданной стилем, смотрим на экран, стили отображаются как надо в 12 колонок и т.д.

Переворачиваем iPad в портретный вид, ширина браузера сокращается до размера меньше 900px, и пример сразу приобретает другой вид, все колонки становятся шириной 100%, но всё работает так, как и задумано.

А теперь ещё раз пройдёмся по [этой таблице](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options) для понимания, что в ней написано:

1. `.col-xs-` - стиль работает при ширине браузера меньше 768px, при всех других разрешениях больше 768px размер будет 100%.
2. `.col-sm-` - стиль работает при ширине браузера больше 768px, если разрешение меньше 768px, то будет 100%.
3. `.col-md-` - стиль работает при ширине браузера больше 992px
4. `.col-lg-` - стиль работает при ширине браузера больше 1200px

Также там есть примеры работы смешанных стилей, в приоритете всегда тот стиль, который подходит под условия и если написано `.col-md-6 .col-sm-6`, то на портретном виде iPad, будет работать стиль `.col-sm-6`.

По поводу разрешения 2048х1536, почитайте про работу дисплеев Retina в браузере, да, они дают больше точек на дюйм, но разрешение браузера совсем другое, [по этой ссылке](http://myresolutionis.ru/) можно увидеть различие. У меня на ноутбуке с Retina выдаёт в открытом на весь экран браузере:

```
Размер окна браузера в пикселях (ширина х высота): 1280 x 676
Разрешение экрана в пикселях (ширина х высота): 2560 x 1600
```

В стилях Twitter Bootstrap определяется первое значение, а, именно, размер окна браузера.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Но не совсем понятно, в чем смысл игнорирования настроек md sm, когда экран определяется как xs. Получается, что нужно всегда обязательно указавыть и то, и другое. И что насчет вертикального смещения вложенных ячеек?

Comment:  1. Когда экран определяется как xs, md и sm становятся равны 100%, что вполне логично для мобильных устройста, если вам нужно, чтобы и на мобильных устройствах было видно колонки с нужным размером, то нужно добавить стиль xs.
 2. По поводу вертикального смещения ячеек, я так понял, имеется в виду разная высота у ячеек. Тут тоже не вижу проблем, у ячеек может быть разная высота, но родительская строка всё равно будет по высоте самой длинной ячейки и вылазить там никуда ничего не может в принципе, `position: absolute;` в этой сетке не применяется.

Comment: сделал скриншот в сафари
http://www.dropshots.com/fortest100/date/2015-01-29/00:49:22

Comment: `Level 1: .col-sm-9` - родительский элемент занимает 75% места на странице, справа 25% пустого места, а внутри лежат элементы, которые занимают 100% ширины `.col-sm-9`. В чём ошибка?

Comment: А да извините, неправильно код прочитал.
Насчет ширины я уже понял, что на устройствах определяемых как xs работают только xs настройки. Учитывая это, выравнивание по ширине работает предсказуемо.