# bootstrap блоки

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка

Вопрос такой, почему в коде, содержащем  2 блока:

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                 <p>1 блок </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                 <p>2 блок</p>
            </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

при уменьшении ширины экрана 2 блок смещается ниже второго, хотя много свободного пространства между двумя надписями '1 блок' и '2 блок'. Как максимально **запретить блоку смещаться вниз при изменении ширины**, а просто сжиматься в внутри себя?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё просто, добавьте к блокам класс `col-xs-6` и блоки не будут смещаться.

```
   <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                 <p>1 блок </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                 <p>2 блок</p>
            </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Просто супер, большое спасибо, пойду читать в доках про такую зависимость)

Comment: Почитайте мой ответ тут: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/394224/